# Split the camera into sections?

Tags: unity

I have a layout for my game similar to this:

[image]

Where the light gray area is reserved for HUD elements and the dark gray area is reserved for the actual game. One function I want to offer in the dark gray area is the ability to zoom and move around, which works independently from the light gray area, meaning that no matter how far I zoom in/out or how far I move, the light gray area remains unaffected.

How can I do this without always taking the offset center into account? How can I completely separate the game play part and the HUD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your UI Canvas to render in ScreenSpace - Overlay, so it's mapped to the screen/window, layered on top of everything at the end of the rendering passes, independent of any camera.

You can configure your camera to render to only the bottom-right section of the screen/window by [configuring its viewport rect in the inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) or [via script](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html).

For example, to render the camera's view to only the bottom-right 80% of the screen/windows's width & height, you'd configure the viewport rect to:

```
x: 0.2   width: 0.8
y: 0.0   height: 0.8
```