# Unity split camera without refit the center

Tags: unity, camera

Before attempting to mark this question as duplicate or send me [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164225/split-the-camera-into-sections), hear me out:

I was trying to make a [coincidence rangefinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coincidence_rangefinder) effect, say I have a view like this:

[image: Sample scene]

In a coincidence rangefinder, it would be split into 2 parts, upper and lower, each produced by a different camera, like this:

[image: Coincidence rangefinder view]

(Note the middle may not be aligned)

But if I directly mark the 2 cameras in Unity by `X Y` and `W H` (`0, 0, 1, 0.5` and `0, 0.5, 1, 1`), they will recenter themselves, producing the following effect:

[image: Not the ideal result]

So how can I change the viewport rectangle so that the camera is clipped instead of refitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect [using an oblique frustum, as described in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ObliqueFrustum.html).

Here's an example that takes two cameras and configures them to occupy the top and bottom halves of the screen, so that combined (if they were looking from the same location/orientation) they appear as one seamless camera view.

```
public class ScreenSplitter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera top;
    public Camera bottom;

    [Range(0.0001f, 179f)]
    [Tooltip("Field of View of the combined camera, in degrees.")]
    public float combinedFOV = 60f;

    // Update the cameras live in the editor so we can preview changes.    
    private void OnValidate() {
        if (top != null && bottom != null)
            UpdateCameraProjection();
    }

    // Apply changes on start-up.
    private void Start() {
        UpdateCameraProjection();        
    }

    // Call this to enable the effect (eg. when switching to the rangefinder view)
    public void UpdateCameraProjection() {
        // At 1 m depth in front of the camera, how high does the top
        // of the frustum rise above the center of the view?
        float imageHeight = Mathf.Tan(combinedFOV * Mathf.Deg2Rad / 2);

        // We want our image from each half-camera to span *half* that height.
        float fov = Mathf.Atan(0.5f * imageHeight) * 2 * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        top.fieldOfView = fov;
        bottom.fieldOfView = fov;

        // Set the viewports for each camera to cover their respective halves.
        top.rect = new Rect(0, 0.5f, 1, 0.5f);
        bottom.rect = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 0.5f);

        // Undo any overrides to the projection matrix to make sure
        // we're working from the standard for this FoV/viewport.
        top.ResetProjectionMatrix();

        // Apply obliqueness - shift so the projection axis
        // is at the bottom of its half-screen.
        var mat = top.projectionMatrix;
        mat[1, 2] = 1f;
        top.projectionMatrix = mat;

        // Repeat for the bottom camera, shifting so the projection axis
        // is at the top of its half-screen.
        bottom.ResetProjectionMatrix();
        mat = bottom.projectionMatrix;
        mat[1, 2] = -1f;
        bottom.projectionMatrix = mat;
    }
}
```